# Does suhosin force some options in php.ini?

Tags: php, suhosin

I can't seem to change some values in php.ini.

For example: display_errors = On

I can only turn it on on runtime.

I suspect that suhosin is messing with this, is there any way to bypass it?

Yes I'm sure I'm editing the right files, but look at this, taken from phpinfo():

Additional .ini files parsed /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/suhosin.ini

But I open suhosin.ini and there is nothing there, only extension=suhosin.so

Comment: check what errors it is 'allowed' to display. For instance does it only show warnings and doesn't show errors / deprecated stuff..

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the right php.ini file ? And are you restarting the PHP server after modifying the php.ini file ? *(if you are using php-fpm, you have to restart php-fpm, and not nginx)*

Comment: Just comment suhosin out and try again, and you will have the answer to your question.

Comment: at least the [suhosin feature list](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/a_feature_list.html) doesnt say so

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your php.ini or suhosin.ini:

```
suhosin.disable.display_errors = Off
```